# Not able to open Facebook user profile using intent

Tags: android, facebook, android-intent

Using the below reference from lot of Stack Overflow answers I have tried to go to a user Facebook profile in my Facebook app. But it takes me to my profile and not the user profile.

In not-app case scenario, the mentioned code gets me to the user profile that is fine for me, but not in the app available case.

```
Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse("fb://page/" + accountname));
intent.setPackage("com.facebook.katana");
if(isAppAvailable(NewProfileActivity.this, intent))
    startActivity(intent); // Just goes to my profile in fb app.
else {
    intent = new Intent(NewProfileActivity.this, SpaceWebView.class); // Goes to webview and displays the user profile perfectly.
    intent.putExtra("url", "https://www.facebook.com/" + accountname);
    startActivity(intent);
}
```

I have also integrated instagram and it works in both the cases.

```
Uri instaURI = Uri.parse("http://instagram.com/_u/" + instaName);
Intent instaIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, instaURI);
instaIntent.setPackage("com.instagram.android");

if(isAppAvailable(NewProfileActivity.this, instaIntent)){
    startActivity(instaIntent); // Goes to user profile in app
}
else{
    Intent intentWithoutApp = new Intent(NewProfileActivity.this, SpaceWebView.class);
    intentWithoutApp.putExtra("url", instaURI.toString());
    startActivity(intentWithoutApp); // Opens user proifile in webview.
}
```

Any help for correct Facebook URI to go to profile with app also.

Comment: Have you solve this problem? I am also need this .